# How to dynamically expand widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, dynamic, layout, responsive

I am trying to achieve a responsive layout with dynamic flex factor on my Expanded

If there is enough space, each row should expand equally:

```
available height: 1600

row 1 - needs 50px to render children -> height 400
row 2 - needs 300px to render children -> height 400
row 3 - needs 150px to render children -> height 400
row 4 - needs 150px to render children -> height 400
```

If the available space is not enough to expand equally, each row should have at least the minimum height their children need and expand if possible

```
available height: 900

row 1 - needs 50px to render children -> height 200
row 2 - needs 300px to render children -> height 300
row 3 - needs 150px to render children -> height 200
row 4 - needs 150px to render children -> height 200
```

If the available space is not enough to render the children of all rows, make it scrollable:

```
available height: 500

row 1 - needs 50px to render children -> height 50
row 2 - needs 300px to render children -> height 300
row 3 - needs 150px to render children -> height 150
row 4 - needs 150px to render children -> height 150

650 > 500  -> gets scrollable
```

Due to long researches my current code looks similar to this

```
return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: constraints.maxHeight),
      child: IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Column(
          children: [
           Expanded(WeekRow()), // 1
           Expanded(WeekRow()), // 2
           Expanded(WeekRow()), // 3
           Expanded(WeekRow()), // 3
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
});
```

And a week looks similar to this:

```
return Column(
      children: [        
          ...entries
              .map(
                (e) => Container(height: 30),
              )
              .toList(),
      ],
    );
```

My problem is that if 1 week holds more than 1/4 of available space, all of the weeks expands to the size of this week, making it scrollable before it should.

Like this:

```
available height: 900

row 1 - needs 50px to render children -> height 300
row 2 - needs 300px to render children -> height 300
row 3 - needs 150px to render children -> height 300
row 4 - needs 150px to render children -> height 300

1200 > 900 > 650 (space needed to render all children) -> scrollable when it shouldn't
```